# Is this shopping site safe from SQL injection attacks?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, security

Please verify security from SQL injection attacks.

**homepage.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="list">
            <li><h3><a href="search.php?name=women-top">tops</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="#">suits</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="#">jeans</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="search.php?name=women">more</a></h3></li>
            </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'shop');

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$lcSearchVal=$_GET['name'];
//echo "hi";
$lcSearcharr=explode("-",$lcSearchVal);
$result=count($lcSearchVal);
//echo $result;



$parts = array();
$parts1=array();
foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord ){
    $parts[] = '`PNAME` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';
    $parts1[] = '`TAGS` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';
    //$parts[] = '`CATEGORY` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';
}
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM xml where ('.implode ('AND',:name).')");
$stmt->bind_Param(':name',$parts);

$list=array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $list[]=$row;
  }
}


    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();
foreach($list as $array)
{
?>
            <div class="image">
<img src="<?php echo $array['IMAGEURL']?>" width="200px" height="200px"/></a>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on a link in homepage.php, it will search from XML for the products related 
to the clicked link.  Please verify whether the SQL statement is secured from a Google bot's attack and whether it's handling the data securely or not.

Comment: Is `$parts1` used at all ?

Comment: no sir.its not used till now.can delete $parts1.

Comment: @Josay-please help on this.i m not able to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not validating and not escaping `$_GET['name']`.

Although [@wouter-j](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/20270/wouter-j) pointed out in a comment that the prepared statement should protect you, [this post on Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/are-prepared-statements-100-safe-against-sql-injection) argues otherwise, so I don't think you should count on it.

And I think you have some errors too. For example if this works, it looks like *magic* to me:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM xml where ('.implode ('AND',:name).')");
$stmt->bind_Param(':name',$parts);
```

Comment: no.its not working sir.Thats why i m looking for help.please correct my code.its giving me serious headache.@Janos

Comment: @user3545382 You might be better of asking stack overflow this question my friend

Comment: Since he is using prepared statements, he doesn't have to escape `$_GET['name']` anymore.

Comment: @WouterJ would you disagree with this post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/are-prepared-statements-100-safe-against-sql-injection

Comment: @janos - I for one would disagree with your linked post.  All I read was a bunch of "if this" and "if that" then "maybe" something bad might happen.  I'd be interested in reading anything that shows an actual exploit especially in the context of mysql and simple sql statements.  Not trying to be hostile but I'd like to see some facts.